# Can almost empty system partitions be shrinked?

Tags: root-access, partitions

[image: Partition table of Xperia T]
The first four partitions take up 422.7 megabytes each, despite every single one doesn't have even one megabyte of content. Does this mean that this space is wasted? Can these partitions be reduced, so that the free space becomes available to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't worry about the first 4 entries.  They are most likely mounted to the same partition, which is why they are showing the same exact sizes.  If you are rooted, install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) and try command `busybox df -h`.  This should give you a better picture.  For example, here's the output on my phone:

```
shell@jgedlte:/ $ su
su
root@jgedlte:/ # busybox df -h
busybox df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   909.7M     84.0K    909.7M   0% /dev
none                    909.7M     12.0K    909.7M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   909.7M         0    909.7M   0% /mnt/asec
tmpfs                   909.7M         0    909.7M   0% /mnt/obb
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system
                          1.1G    945.3M    164.9M  85% /system
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata
                         12.7G      7.9G      4.8G  62% /data
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache
                         31.5M      5.1M     26.5M  16% /cache
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/apnhlos
                         86.0M      8.7M     77.2M  10% /firmware
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mdm
                         86.0M     49.6M     36.3M  58% /firmware-mdm
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/efs
                         13.4M      4.3M      9.2M  32% /efs
/dev/fuse                12.7G      7.9G      4.8G  62% /mnt/shell/emulated
/dev/block/vold/179:33
                         59.5G     12.4G     47.0G  21% /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard
/dev/fuse                59.5G     12.4G     47.0G  21% /storage/extSdCard
root@jgedlte:/ #
```

Second, no, you cannot re-size partitions on your phone.  You would most likely render your phone inoperable if you tried, but most devices won't let you do this anyway.

It looks like your phone model has 8GB of internal memory, out of which only 4GB (3.8 formatted) is available for user apps and data.  I would start looking into the 2.3GB you have used up to see if anything can be trimmed there.  Lowest hanging fruit is clearing app cache (Settings -> Apps -> Downloaded -> sort by size,) downloaded files (Apps -> Downloads,) and crash logs (Apps -> Dialer -> dial `*#9900#` -> tap `Delete dumpstate/logcat`.)  If you are running Android version that allows moving apps to SD Card natively, you should take advantage of that.  If not - there are other solutions but they require rooting your device.

Comment: But I did resize my partitions. I reduced the size of emulated SD Card, and increased the size of my /data partition so I have more space for my apps. I will look into the Busybox thing you've pointed out, thanks!